# 1D CNN in Keras: Flattening from pooled features to dense layer raises ValueError

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have the following CNN model defined. it is expecting a 1D vector input of length 501.

```
model = ml.models.Sequential()
model.add(ml.layers.Conv1D(filters=NUMBER_OF_FILTERS, kernel_size=KERNEL_SIZE, activation=ACTIVATION, input_shape=(None, 501)))
model.add(ml.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=POOL_SIZE, padding='valid'))
model.add(ml.layers.Flatten())
model.add(ml.layers.Dense(HIDDEN_SIZE-1, activation=ACTIVATION))
```

Yet this raises a value error:

```
ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`.
```

I am not sure why Flatten is not creating a shape of something like `(None, x)`, but instead `(None, None)`. What seems to be the problem here?

This is the model summary:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d (Conv1D)              (None, None, 50)          250550    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d (MaxPooling1D) (None, None, 50)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, None)              0         
=================================================================
Total params: 250,550
Trainable params: 250,550
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the solution. I was not correctly defining the input_shape of the Conv1D Layer, it should instead be:

```
model.add(ml.layers.Conv1D(filters=NUMBER_OF_FILTERS, kernel_size=KERNEL_SIZE, activation=ACTIVATION, input_shape=(501, 1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Layers Flatten transforms the format of the images from a two-dimensional array (a,b) to a one-dimensional array (aXb).Layer Pooling out-put max_pooling1d (MaxPooling1D) (None, None, 50)  a two-dimensional array (0,0).So layer Flatten : flatten (Flatten)            (None, None)